# Composing SQL insert statement into another insert statement

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I know that in T-SQL (Server 2008 R2) I can use the 'Output' keyword to get the Id of a row I just inserted. For example, I can do

```
insert into [Membership].[dbo].[User] (EmailAddress) 
output Inserted.UserId 
values('testUser1@test.com')
```

Is there any way of composing this into another insert? For example, lets say I want to add a new user and immediately add that user to a `UserRole` table which maps the `UserId` to a `RoleId`.

Basically, I would like to do something like below.

```
insert into UserRole (RoleId, UserId) 
values 
(
    1, 
    insert into [Membership].[dbo].[User] (EmailAddress) 
    output Inserted.UserId values('testUser1@test.com')
)
```

But I can't seem to get this to work. I tried wrapping the internal insert in brackets () or using a select * from () etc.

What am I missing? Is this composition even possible?

Thanks for the help.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to capture the output into a table variable:

```
DECLARE @TempVar TABLE (UserID INT)

insert into [Membership].[dbo].[User] (EmailAddress) 
output Inserted.UserId INTO @TempVar(UserID)
values('testUser1@test.com')
```

and then in a second step do an insert from that temp table into the target table:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.UserRole (RoleId, UserId) 
   SELECT 
      (yourRoleId), tv.UserID
   FROM @TempVar tv
```

You could also direct the `OUTPUT` clause directly into the target table - that'll work if you can e.g. use a fixed value for your `RoleID`:

```
DECLARE @FixedRoleID INT = 42

INSERT INTO [Membership].[dbo].[User] (EmailAddress) 
OUTPUT @FixedRoleID, Inserted.UserId INTO dbo.UserRole(RoleId, UserId)
VALUES ('testUser1@test.com')
```

Comment: I knew I could have used temporary tables, but I wanted to see if there was a way to compose it from one query to another without any intermediate storage. Seems like your last option does exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use triggers:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

and pay attention to "after" insert triggers:

> FOR | AFTER AFTER specifies that the DML trigger is fired only when
>   all operations specified in the triggering SQL statement have executed
>   successfully. All referential cascade actions and constraint checks
>   also must succeed before this trigger fires.
>
> AFTER is the default when FOR is the only keyword specified.
>
> AFTER triggers cannot be defined on views.